# Which permissions are required for PCFAgent enquiries?

Tags: java, permissions, monitoring, ibm-mq, pcf

I'm using a little application I wrote to enquire about the state of some queues on a QM. The enquiry itself is done using the `PCFAgent`/`PCFMessageAgent` java classes.

My question is: which (least) privileges must be granted to allow a certain MCA user to run **monitoring** PCF commands (in particular, `MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q_STATUS` and `MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q`)?

Note: by "monitoring" I mean that the commands should not alter the state of the queue manager in any appreciable way.

Comment: Letting the bounty expire?  An answer from myself and Dale Lane are about as credible/official as it gets!

Comment: I was just waiting for the deadline. I would have awarded it afterwards anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!  Feel free to post follow-up questions if any clarifications are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program must be able to do the following:

- Connect & inquire on the QMgr
- Create a model queue using inquire, display and get authority against a suitable model queue (you'd generally define a dedicated one for this rather than using the default model queue)
- Put PCF messages on the command queue with inquire, display and put authority
- Inquire on the target queue with display authority

Dale Lane wrote a blog post a while back describing this for the general case of: *[Using WebSphere MQ Explorer as a read-only viewer](https://hursleyonwmq.wordpress.com/2007/02/08/using-websphere-mq-explorer-as-a-read-only-viewer/)*.  Since WMQ Explorer needs to display all objects of all object types it is a bit more permissive than you are asking for.  However, the settings you need are a subset of the ones Dale provides and the post has a lot of good background on the configurations used.  I could copy his `setmqaut` commands here but its worth reading the post.

Incidentally, if you have a v7.1 QMgr and a new WMQ Explorer (downloaded from [SupportPac MS0T](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMS0T)) there's a security wizard in WMQ Explorer that makes the same settings Dale recommends in his blog post.